# Html5 video player have to press pause twice when on autoplay

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, mp4

I am using the code in this codepen http://codepen.io/frytyler/pen/juGfk to make custom controls for my video player which works great except when I have the video set to "autoplay" like in the code below. It plays the video but I then have to press pause twice to pause it, how would I modify the code to solve this?

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay controls preload="auto" poster="http://s.cdpn.io/6035/vp_poster.jpg" width="380" >
```

Comment: Where to press? pause button or screen?

Comment: Either, you have to press the screen twice or the play/pause button twice on autoplay

Answer (score 2):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZwxed

It's quick solution for screen, adding this snippet at last line of js inside of dom.ready().

```
     //doubleclick
    $('#myVideo').click(function () {
       if ($("#myVideo").get(0).paused) {
           $("#myVideo").get(0).play();
       } 
    });

     $('#myVideo').dblclick(function () {


       $("#myVideo").get(0).pause();

});
```

there a problem, play/pause button may act weird when you click button after of click twice in screen, you need to assign play/pause button class to display properly or it would look best if you hide this button.

EDIT:
You may manipulate play/pause button in following code:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
     vid.onplaying = function() {
  //call when video is playing, it should show pause icon in button like .addClass and .removeClass
};
     vid.onpause = function() {
  //call when video is paused, it should show play icon in button like .addClass and .removeClass
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves the issue only if I told them to double click though, if you set your codepen to autoplay it still doesn't pause it right away, it's still shows the play state even thought the video is playing.

Comment: It works for me even i added autoplay on this html tag, maybe you clicked three times

Comment: It needs to work without double clicking though, the play button is still in the play state when the video starts playing, I need the JS to recognize that it is playing and go to the pause state so you only have to click once to pause the video.

Comment: That needs some time, I'm still busy right now, you have to find this script where it toggles play and pause icon button, I edited my answer, so you can handle it, don't forget to remove original functions where you copied it may cause conflicts.

Comment: I will see what I can do with that, thanks for your time!

Comment: If you don't mind if you may accept my answer, thanks